# Is there a javascript implementation to generate your Monero subaddresses without giving out your private-spend key?

Tags: address, privatekey, sub-address, javascript, spend-key

I want to create an online widget where one can output their subaddresses without having to input their private-spend key and only use the other keys provided. Is there a javascript implementation of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use this Javascript NPM package to generate subaddresses: https://www.npmjs.com/package/subaddress

Answer (score 0):

Subaddresses are created using the private *view* key of the base address, not the private *spend* key. See https://monerodocs.org/public-address/subaddress/#generating and https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2056.

There is no way to create a subaddress without the base address private view key.